# Angular send complicated object to Flask by Json

Tags: json, angular, typescript, flask

I am a green hand in using Angular. I have to send a complicated object to the back end. But I just know how to pass on simple information currently, number or string for example, by using `Observable` and URL.

I wanna know how to **change the object(id&note) into one json object** in Angular and then delivery it to the back end.

1. Code:

(1) Angular: dealing.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostDealingService {
    private URL_SEND_NOTE = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/note'

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
      ) { }

    sendNote(id: string, note: string): Observable<any> {       
        return this.http.get(`${this.URL_SEND_NOTE}/${id}&${note}`)
    }
}
```

(2) Angular: table.component.ts

```js
  /** about note */
  sendNote(id: number, event: any) {
    if(event.target.value.length <= 0) {
      return
    }
    // event.target.value = note
    this.pds.sendNote(String(id), event.target.value)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("end note normal", data)
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error')
      }
    )
  }
```

(3) Flask:

```py
@app.route('/note/<id>&<note>', methods=['get', 'post'])
def updateNote(id, note):
    print(id, note)
    c_33.updateNote(conn_33, cur_33, id, note)
    return "1"
```

Versions:

(1) Angular:

```sh
Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.15
@angular/cli                      9.1.15
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15
@schematics/angular               9.1.15
@schematics/update                0.901.15
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

(2) npm

```sh
6.14.5
```

Comment: you are using a get request, instead you might use a post request for updating/creating a note

Comment: @Mar Yes, you are right! Thanks for your reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the POST request: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

```
sendNote(id: string, note: string): Observable<any> {       
        return this.http.post(this.URL_SEND_NOTE, {id: id, note: note});
}
```

You can then use `request.get_json()` at the backend to retrieve the POST body.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to update existing note. In that case, you should use PUT request. https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-put-request

```
updateNote(id: string, note: string): Observable<any> {       
    return this.http.put(this.URL_SEND_NOTE + '/' + id, note);
}
```

or if you want to have id in request body:

```
updateNote(id: string, note: string): Observable<any> {       
    return this.http.put(this.URL_SEND_NOTE + '/' + id, {id: id, note: note});
}
```

On Flask side change request method:

```
@app.route('/note/<id>', methods=['put'])
def updateNote(id):
    ...
```